# Problema em salvar relacionamento muitos para muitos com Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, relacionamento, entity-framework-core

Estou com problema em salvar um relacionamento de muitos para muitos com *Entity Framework Core*

Tenho as seguintes entidades

```
[Table("quadros")]
public class Quadro : BaseEntity
{
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public List<CheckList> Checklists { get; set; }
    public bool Concluido { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataUltimaOperacao { get; set; }
    public List<UsuarioQuadro> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public long EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public List<Atividade> Atividades { get; set; }
}


[Table("usuarios")]
public class Usuario : BaseEntity
{
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string SobreNome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int TipoUsuario { get; set; }
    public long EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public List<UsuarioQuadro> Quadros { get; set; }
    public List<Atividade> Atividades { get; set; }
}
```

**entidade de relacionamento**

```
[Table("usuarioQuadro")]
public class UsuarioQuadro : BaseEntity
{
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public long UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public Quadro Quadro { get; set; }
    public long QuadroId { get; set; }
}
```

**Meu DataContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
 modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioQuadro>()
     .HasKey(uq => new { uq.UsuarioId, uq.QuadroId });  
   modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioQuadro>()
        .HasOne(u => u.Usuario)
        .WithMany(uq => uq.Quadros)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.UsuarioId)  
    modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioQuadro>()
        .HasOne(q => q.Quadro)
        .WithMany(uq => uq.Usuarios)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.QuadroId);
}
```

porém quando vou salvar o quadro com os usuários recebo a seguinte *Exeception*

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'UsuarioId' on entity type 'UsuarioQuadro' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.'

Comment: Não sei se tem relação, mas acho que na sua `BaseEntity` tenha um campo para **ID**, talvez o problema esteja ao tentar fazer a chave composta `.HasKey(uq => new { uq.UsuarioId, uq.QuadroId }); `. Tente remover a chave composta e deixar apenas a *PK*

Comment: no EF Core, você não precisa colocar os campos `long UsuarioId` ele reconhece a composição como chave automaticamente, não precisa nem mexer no `OnModelCreating`

Comment: @Barbetta Fiz o teste porem sem sucesso, creio que precisa de mapear a chave composta, pois fiz igual esta na documentacao EF Core no site da Microsoft  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Posso remover as propriedades `UsuarioId` e `QuadroId` da entidade `UsuarioQuadro`
e também remover todo o mapeamento da referente a entidade `UsuarioQuadro` na `OnModelCreating`
  ?

Comment: Falta você colocar o código que faz o preenchimento dos dados antes de salvar. Normalmente se forem novos registros (você não tem o ID), você apenas faz o set das instâncias no UsuarioQuadro e adiciona na lista. O EF vai preencher os IDs depois que salvar a entity.

Comment: sim, e me parece que não é necessário que UsuarioQuadro  herde BaseEntity (que deve possuir uma PK), você deve definir Usuario e Quadro como [KEY]

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no erro acima, eu creio que você poderia colocar no `modelBuilder`:

```
modelBuilder.Property(x => x.userId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```